# Symfony enable custom bundle ClassNotFoundException

Tags: php, symfony

I want to install my own bundle so I did 
    composer require "al37350/fftt-bundle": "*"

Then I activated the bundle in AppKernel.php

```
new Al\FFTTBundle\AlFFTTBundle(),
```

But when I did a php/bin console I have this error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "AlFFTTBundle" from namespace "Al\FFTTBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /var/www/yoloFFTT/app/AppKernel.php:19
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/yoloFFTT/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(450): AppKernel->registerBundles()
#1 /var/www/yoloFFTT/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(116): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
#2 /var/www/yoloFFTT/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(137): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
#3 /var/www/yoloFFTT/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(124): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->registerCommands()
#4 /var/www/yoloFFTT/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(90): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->add(Object(Symfony\Co in /var/www/yoloFFTT/app/AppKernel.php on line 19
```

File structure of bundle :

```
src
    Al
        FFTTBundle
```

and the namespace of AlFFTTBundle.php is Al\FFTTBundle;

When the bundle isn't in the vendor directory, it's work, any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the composer.json in your bundle contain psr-0 or psr-4 autoloading?

Example:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Al\\FFTTBundle\\": "src/AlFFTTBundle",
    }
}
```

For more info see: https://seld.be/notes/psr-4-autoloading-support-in-composer.

Comment: I think one should mention that any supported composer autoloading mechanism would work (PSR-4, PSR-0, classmap and files).

Answer (score 0):

After making this entry in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Al\\FFTTBundle\\": "src/AlFFTTBundle",
    }
}
```

run : `composer dump-autoload`