# ClassNotFoundError after installing custom Symfony Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I created a simple custom Symfony bundle (in version 5.0). It's after I ran `composer require` located in `vendor/ntrx/ntrx-user-bundle`, but I'm not able to load it normally. The folder structure there is like this:

```
Controller/
Service/
composer.json
NtrxUserBundle.php
Readme.md
```

The `composer.json` contains the following:

```
{
    "name": "ntrx/ntrx-user-bundle",
    "description": "",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        [...]
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Ntrx\\UserBundle\\": "" }
    }
}
```

And the `NtrxUserBundle.php` contains the following code:

```
<?php

namespace Ntrx\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class NtrxUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container): void {
        parent::build($container);
    }
}
```

When I ran for example `php bin/console` I get the following error:

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\ClassNotFoundError^ {#31
  #message: """
    Attempted to load class "NtrxUserBundle" from namespace "Ntrx\UserBundle".\n
    Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
    """
  #code: 0
  #file: "./src/Kernel.php"
  #line: 23
  trace: {
    ./src/Kernel.php:23 {
      App\Kernel->registerBundles(): iterable^
      › if ($envs[$this->environment] ?? $envs['all'] ?? false) {
      ›     yield new $class();
      › }
    }
    ./vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:369 { …}
    ./vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:123 { …}
    ./vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:169 { …}
    ./vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:75 { …}
    ./vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:140 { …}
    ./bin/console:42 { …}
  }
}
```

I tried to change the names of the bundle or to change the autoloader, but it seems that the class isn't there at all. I also tried to break an other third-party bundle (make a typo in the class name) and I get an corresponding error there but not the error above (`The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.`). Also `composer dump-autoload` doesn't change anything.

The only similar error I found in the web is [Symfony enable custom bundle ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865694/symfony-enable-custom-bundle-classnotfoundexception) and I think that there's everything correkt in my code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have this problem in isolation or only when requiring the bundle in a symfony project?

Comment: Did your Symfony project's composer.json file get updated with the ntrx dependency?  Might check the generated autoload files to see if there is an ntrx entry.

Answer (score 0):

Even though its an pretty old question, maybe this helps someone:

In case you changed or added namespaces you should run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

After that, Symfony is able to find your classes again.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @Cerad for the hint to check the autoload files of composer. There in the `autoload_psr4.php` the autoload folder was defined in `vendor/ntrx/ntrx-user-bundle/src`. But the class is in `vendor/ntrx/ntrx-user-bundle`. The additional subfolder `src` was part of a new change of the bundle.

I completly removed the `vendor` folder, executed `composer clear-cache` and installed all packages with composer. Than it works!

I missed to clear the cache of composer after this change of the autoloader.